# Use Axum Multipart for S3 upload

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, rust-axum

I have a multipart form endpoint in my Axum app. File upload form field is supposed to be read like this:

```
// let mut field: axum::extract::multipart::Field
while let Some(chunk) = field.chunk().await? {
    // Do something with chunk: Bytes
}
// Done
```

On other side I have `s3::Bucket` (`rust-s3` crate) and its method `put_object_stream` expects `tokio::io::AsyncRead`. How to make them work together without saving the whole file in the memory or on the disk?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multipart [`Field`](https://docs.rs/axum/0.6.20/axum/extract/multipart/struct.Field.html) and want to use it as a `tokio::io::AsyncRead` type, you can use [`tokio_util::io::StreamReader`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.7.9/tokio_util/io/struct.StreamReader.html) since `Field` [implements](https://docs.rs/axum/0.6.20/axum/extract/multipart/struct.Field.html#impl-Stream-for-Field%3C%27a%3E) `Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, MultipartError>>`. Though because `AsyncRead`'s interface uses `std::io::Error` you'll have to convert `MultipartError` to it first.

```ini
[dependencies] # additional
futures = "0.3.28"
tokio-util = { version = "0.7.9", features = ["io"] }
```

```
use axum::extract::multipart::Field;
use futures::TryStreamExt;
use tokio_util::io::StreamReader;

let field: Field = ...;

let reader = StreamReader::new(field.map_err(|multipart_error| {
    std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, multipart_error)
}));
```